# Response.End() causes session lost the first time session is used

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I have a site built using MVC 2. My problem is that Response.End() causes session lost *the first time* session is accessed.

**Test case 1:**

1. Start the application.
2. Go to Home/X. An item is added to `session` and `Response.End()` is called.
3. Open Home/X again and check `Session["X"]` (add a break point before the assignation line.) It returns **null.** Execute the rest of the action which assign "X" to session again.
4. Reopen Home/X. This time `Session["X"]` returns correct value.

**Test case 2:**

1. Keep the web application running. Close the browser and reopen to open a new session. Visit Home/X.
2. Result: `Session["X"]` always has a value.

Could anyone please explain to me why this happens and how to solve it?

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }
    public void X()
    {
        Session["X"] = "X";
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/a/329523/1557322. Hope this info will help you.

Comment: I think you confused browser session with asp.net session.

Comment: @ViralShah but I have no problem with ViewState here

Comment: @MaksimVi. Nope, I don't. Test case #2 shows that the problem happens only once right after the application starts and Sesion is accessed the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
    public void Session_OnStart()
    {
    }
```

to Global.asax helps fix the problem.